# Regex exercise, parsing an accidentally messed up string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string

```
str = (größen xs-xxl)s+m+l+xl+xxl+xxxl(Solid-Farben)Dark Grey (2890)+Black (9000)+Mocca (5050)+Cognac (5048)
```

consisting of four parts:

```
1: (größen xs-xxl)
2: s+m+l+xl+xxl+xxxl

3: (Solid-Farben)
4: Dark Grey (2890)+Black (9000)+Mocca (5050)+Cognac (5048)
```

Originally, the string describes color- and size-variations, and is always put together in the same way:

**1)** The first key (the name of the size or color category, this time *"größen xs-xxl"* in parentheses
**2)** The values of the first key, separated by plus signs
**3)** The second key (this time *"Solid-Farben"*) in parentheses
**4)** The values of the second key, separated by plus signs. Unfortunately, there are spaces and parentheses as part of the value-string as well.

All parts are simply glued together, and it is my job to reverse engineer that stuff.
So far, I already crafted this regex with the following ideas in mind:

First I need the key names inside brackets, so get everything inside the brackets:

```
(\([^+)]+\))
```

Since this also captures the numbers inside brackets belonging to the values of the second key (e.g. *(2890)*, the second part is a negative lookahead assertion testing for a plus sign or line end after the closing bracket.

```
(?!\+|$)
```

Those put together capture the key components of my string:

```
regex = /(\([^+)]+\))(?!\+|$)/
1.9.3-p374 :085 > str.scan regex
=> [["(größen xs-xxl)"], ["(Solid-Farben)"]]
```

Now I am getting desperate trying to also extract the corresponding values. Of course I could iterate over the key array, splitting the source string and processing the collected results - but this is very ugly.
A more elegant approach is to double the regex and add a **(.+)** in between to get the trailing value-part:

```
regex = (\([^+)]+\))(?!\+|$)(.+?)(\([^+)]+\))(.+?)$
1.9.3-p374 :096 > str.scan regex
=> [["(größen xs-xxl)", "s+m+l+xl+xxl+xxxl", "(Solid-Farben)", "Dark Grey (2890)+Black (9000)+Mocca (5050)+Cognac (5048)"]]
```

, which is exactly as I want it. But despite being almost as ugly as post processing the first regex, this solution doesn't take into consideration that there could be a third key, with corresponding values, also added to the original string:

```
1: (größen xs-xxl)
2: s+m+l+xl+xxl+xxxl

3: (Solid-Farben)
4: Dark Grey (2890)+Black (9000)+Mocca (5050)+Cognac (5048)

5: (NEW DIMENSION)
6: V-NECK+O-NECK+SIZE(tall)+SIZE(short)

str2 = (größen xs-xxl)s+m+l+xl+xxl+xxxl(Solid-Farben)Dark Grey (2890)+Black (9000)+Mocca (5050)+Cognac (5048)(NEW DIMENSION)V-NECK+O-NECK+SIZE(tall)+SIZE(short)
```

This breaks in every way, as I now need **three** captures. Of course my original regex is only designed to match two occurrences, but what if I don't know how many parts are "glued together"?

Could someone with a bigger brain than mine please enlighten me? I would like to see this done with more grace, and as a bonus feature, extended to unlimited occurrences (or even only one) of the original parts before "glueing together" to the source string. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below `string.scan` function.

```
> str = "(größen xs-xxl)s+m+l+xl+xxl+xxxl(Solid-Farben)Dark Grey (2890)+Black (9000)+Mocca (5050)+Cognac (5048)(NEW DIMENSION)V-NECK+O-NECK+SIZE(tall)+SIZE(short)"
> str.scan(/\([^()]*\).*?(?=\((?![\w\d]+\))[^\)]*\)|$)/)
=> ["(größen xs-xxl)s+m+l+xl+xxl+xxxl", "(Solid-Farben)Dark Grey (2890)+Black (9000)+Mocca (5050)+Cognac (5048)", "(NEW DIMENSION)V-NECK+O-NECK+SIZE(tall)+SIZE(short)"]

> str.scan(/(\([^()]*\))(.*?)(?=\((?![\w\d]+\))[^\)]*\)|$)/)
=> [["(größen xs-xxl)", "s+m+l+xl+xxl+xxxl"], ["(Solid-Farben)", "Dark Grey (2890)+Black (9000)+Mocca (5050)+Cognac (5048)"], ["(NEW DIMENSION)", "V-NECK+O-NECK+SIZE(tall)+SIZE(short)"]]
```

Comment: Yes, there's only a marginal difference between the result of _scan_ and _split_ in this case. Unfortunately, this doesn't improve the regex, nor the fact that there could be be more than two key-value-pairs.

Comment: your regex matches correctly. https://regex101.com/r/dH4cL3/4 i don't know what's wrong with that. a more complex input along with expected output would be better.

Comment: You used the wrong string, please try it on the bottom most one. A third key-value-pair was added there, yet there are only two matches.

Comment: i used the bottom most one. It correctly splits the input to 4 parts.

Comment: provide the expected output for the last one.

Comment: edited the question. Output should capture all of the parts, e.g. in the second string there are three key-value-pairs, not only two. Output from a solution would be:   `[["(größen xs-xxl)", "s+m+l+xl+xxl+xxxl", "(Solid-Farben)", "Dark Grey (2890)+Black (9000)+Mocca (5050)+Cognac (5048)","(NEW DIMENSION)", "-NECK+O-NECK+SIZE(tall)+SIZE(short)" ]]`

Comment: Hey could you please cancel the downvote? I made the question even clearer, and you didn't understand the requirements...

Comment: @Mustermax check my update. And i'm not the downvoter.

Comment: You're a regex god obviously, I'll look into your solution :) Sorry for suspecting you of the downvote, I put so much effort into the question.